# Append a div before first row of inner div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to append a div before some inner div, using jQuery. This is my html structure:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">  
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="inner inner_1">1</div>
        <div class="inner inner_2">2</div>
        <div class="inner inner_3">3</div>
        <div class="inner inner_4">4</div>
        <div class="inner inner_5">5</div>
        <div class="inner inner_6">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here my first row of inner div is inner_1 to inner_6. I have some media queries. Due to this media query if we take this in window width less than 400px then my first raw of inner div is inner_1 to inner_3, second row is inner_4 to inner_6.

I want to insert `<div class="item active"> </div>` in first row of inner div and  `<div class="item"> </div>` in second raw of inner div.

For example: the result I need to get in ***window width more than 400px*** is

```
<div class="item active">
        <div class="inner inner_1">1</div>
        <div class="inner inner_2">2</div>
        <div class="inner inner_3">3</div>
        <div class="inner inner_4">4</div>
        <div class="inner inner_5">5</div>
        <div class="inner inner_6">6</div>
</div>
```

The result I need to get in ***window width less than 400px*** is

```
<div class="item active">
        <div class="inner inner_1">1</div>
        <div class="inner inner_2">2</div>
        <div class="inner inner_3">3</div>
</div>       

<div class="item">
        <div class="inner inner_4">4</div>
        <div class="inner inner_5">5</div>
        <div class="inner inner_6">6</div>
</div>
```

How to do this?

To calculate how many items in a row I have the following function:

```
function countFirstRowItems(parentSelector, childSelector){
        var count = 0, theTop = undefined;
        $(parentSelector + " > " + childSelector).each(function(){
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
            if(theTop === undefined){
                theTop = thisTop;
            }
            if(thisTop != theTop){
                return false;
            }
            count++;
        });
        return count;
    }
```

so if we write

```
var no_first_row_item=countFirstRowItems(".carousel-inner",".inner");
```

then if the window width **more than 400px** it will return 6, and if **window width less than 400px** then it will return 3.

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lt/gt pseudoselector

if you want to use your `no_first_row_item` value you will need to do something like

```
var no_first_row_item=countFirstRowItems(".carousel-inner",".inner");
 $('.inner').unwrap();
 $('.inner:lt('+no_first_row_item+')').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
 $('.inner:gt('+(no_first_row_item-1)+')').wrapAll('<div class="item">');
```

or use the windows width to trigger the code on page resize

```
var width = $(window).width();

if(width > 400) {
 $('.inner').unwrap();
 $('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
} else {
 $('.inner').unwrap();
  $('.inner:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
  $('.inner:gt(2)').wrapAll('<div class="item">');
}
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/Lk3pgtje/1/

Comment: Thank you friend . But is it possible to do this without using (width > 400)  ? . Because i have many media queries , not only width >400 . Also what happen if i resized the window .

Comment: what do you mean without the if statement?

Comment: You can do with that count value which you get from countFirstRowItems function

Comment: Thank you friend . But is it possible to do this without using (width > 400) ? . Because i have many media queries , not only width >400 . Also what happen if i resized the window .

Comment: if you have multiple breakpoints use a case structure, use a resize event like in the demo

Comment: Could you please look athis question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072919/arrange-bootstrap-carousel-item-as-per-width . This the same type of question .

Comment: I have a doubt, i need to write this code in two times one for  to add item div in first page load and  one for  to add item div in resize  event  ?  .

Comment: yes you can create a function or you can trigger the resize when the page is loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130376/discussion-between-john-and-madalin-ivascu).